# If $A,B$ isomorphic rings then $Quot(A)$ and $Quot(B)$ are also isomorph

Tags: abstract-algebra

Assume that L is a field , let $y:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow L$ be the homomorphism $y(n)=n\cdot 1$. Assume $ker(y)=0$ then because of homorphismtheorem $Z/\{0\}=\mathbb{Z}$ is isomorph to $im(y):= L_0$. The argument is now that $\mathbb{Q}=Quot(\mathbb{Z})$ is isomorph to $Quot(L_0)$

I dont understand the argument. Also is it necessary that A,B are integral domain is im(y) an integral domain ?

Comment: $\mathbb Z$ and $L_0$ are "the same" (isomorphic).  Up to the relabeling of elements they are essentially the same ring.  If two rings are the same then their quotient rings are also the same (isomorphic).  What do you not understand?

Comment: Also $\operatorname{Quot}(A)$ does make sense when $A$ is not necessarily integral domain.